# ASP.NET web.config - add dll-file

Tags: asp.net, dll, web-config, dllimport

I have a question about the web.config in a asp.net website. For a project I use a dll to communicate with a smartcard-reader. Everything works when I use the website at localhost. But when I put the site online, it won't work anymore.. It does not find the dll anymore because it is blocked somehow ...

I think the web.config must be addapted, but I don't now what to change to let the site communicate with the dll. Mayby a httpModule or httpHandler?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library needs to be in the /bin or [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You may need to [register](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) the .dll if there is not an installer:

```
Regsvr32 -i "C:\path\your.dll"
```

Comment: The dll I'm talking about is the winscard.dll (under c:\\Windows\) and I have put this dll also in the Bin-folder of the website.

I have tried your command but I got an error while doing it:
"Module 'winscard.dll' is loaded, but the accespoint DLLRegisterServer is not found. Make sure that'winscard.dll' is a valid DLL- or OCX file and try it again'

I have searched this error but don't find a solution for the problem..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `winscard.dll` is part of the regular Windows API, see [Authentication Functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Since it's part of the OS, it's probably a bad idea to copy it around.

The question is, what are you trying to do?  ASP.NET code runs on a server, and cannot access a smartcard reader on a remote machine.

If you have a Windows domain, one way to use a smartcard in a website is to let the end user login to the webserver by setting IIS to Windows Integrated Authentication.

Comment: I'm still a student, and the website is for the students with their student card. Here is a link to a test-site of our project ( language is dutch, I'm from belgium) http://pietereggermont.ikdoeict.be/app2/Login.aspx At your right you can see login fields and also a card reader dropdown.

So when we log in, the login is checked on a database and with the login data on the smartcard. This works on local host but not online on webserver.

We use this development kit:
http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&prod_sections=0&id=ACR38-CCID-SDK

Comment: This cardreader has standard code included to communicate with the card and the WINSCARD.DLL is used in code like this:
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public static extern int SCardReleaseContext(Int64 phContext);


So that is why I think the webserver cannot access the winscard.dll, because of a missing code rule or something. But don't know which one

Comment: Setting your [ASP.NET process identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc1xthy.aspx) to "system" should exclude any rights issues.  But even if you got the website to access `winscard.dll`, it can still only talk to card readers connected to the web server.

Comment: I don't get it .. In Machine.config place the following code:
<system.web>
  <processModel enable="true"
    userName="LOCALMACHINE\IUSR_ProcessUser"
    password="%Hco94*#QW12"/>
</system.web>

I only have web.config in my website and it won't accept the code above

Comment: Machine.config is somewhere in c:\windows\microsoft.net\  The process identity can only be changed in machine.config, or any website could declare itself administrator.

Comment: still doensn't work .. can it not be a httpmodule or something like it for my problem?